# Can a large $V_\alpha$ satisfy Comparability but not be well-orderable?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Say that a set satisfies *Comparability* if any two of its subsets are comparable: one is injectable into the other.

Are there models of ZF containing ranks $V_\alpha$ which satisfy Comparability but are not well-orderable, where $\alpha$ is greater than an inaccessible cardinal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is consistent; for instance, if $A$ is an **amorphous set.**

An amorphous set is an infinite set which cannot be partitioned into two infinite pieces: if $A=B\sqcup C$, then either $B$ or $C$ is finite. It's easy to show that any two subsets of an amorphous set are comparable, and the existence of amorphous sets is consistent with $ZF$.

---

I'm not sure I understand your second question - are you asking whether there are models where $V_\alpha$ satisfies comparability for $\alpha$ greater than an inaccessible, but $V_\alpha$ is not well-orderable? Or are you asking merely whether the existence of non-well-orderable sets satisfying comparability is consistent with ZF + there is an inaccessible?

The answer to the second question is yes; to the first, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, Noah! It's the first question you mention that I'm interested in. The simple example you suggest is great, but ultimately not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll edit to make this clear.

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, Noah, but would you mind deleting your answer so I can delete the question? I appreciate the time you put into it.

Comment: @GME Why do you want to delete the question? It's a really good one (I'm still thinking about it btw :P). If you really want to, I will, but I'd encourage you to leave it up.

Comment: If you're still thinking about it, I'll certainly leave it up. (My initial hope was that you or Asaf would be able to answer it, but you'd said you didn't know and Asaf didn't seem to want to answer it, so I thought I'd post it on mathoverflow.) Anyway, I appreciate your looking into it!

Comment: @GME: Asaf is allowed to have dinner not in front of this site from time to time, thank you very much.

Comment: @Asaf: Tsk. Don’t you know that the set doctor is required to be on call 29 hours a day?

Comment: @Brian: As long as it's not $\omega$ hours a day, I'm fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It wasn't clear if your comment was intended to be tongue in cheek, but just in case: the reason I said you didn't seem like you wanted to answer was because of your (frankly hostile) responses to me in the comments on your original answer (which you've now deleted). Not because you hadn't answered.